# How can we add quotes around a string in a column in a data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a field named 'location'; it looks like this.

```
3200 PROVIDENCE DRIVE ANCHORAGE 99508
2500 SOUTH WOODWORTH LOOP PALMER 99645
3260 HOSPITAL DR JUNEAU 99801
1650 COWLES STREET FAIRBANKS 99701
2801 DEBARR ROAD ANCHORAGE 99508
```

I am trying to add double quotes around the string, so it looks like this.

```
"3200 PROVIDENCE DRIVE ANCHORAGE 99508"
"2500 SOUTH WOODWORTH LOOP PALMER 99645"
"3260 HOSPITAL DR JUNEAU 99801"
"1650 COWLES STREET FAIRBANKS 99701"
"2801 DEBARR ROAD ANCHORAGE 99508"
```

I tried this (it does something very weird):

```
for col in results:
    results['location'] =  results['location'].apply(lambda x: """ + str(x) + """)
```

I also tried this (it adds way too many quotes):

```
for col in results:
    results['location'] = '"' + results['location'] + '"'
```

Thoughts?

Comment: `""" + str(x) + """` is a single triple quoted string. See [String and Bytes literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Comment: This appears to be a pandas dataframe. If so, please note. Posting a working script that initializes a test dataframe (minus columns that don't matter for the problem) helps give tested answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ASH, try this:

```
words = ['3200 PROVIDENCE DRIVE ANCHORAGE 99508',
'2500 SOUTH WOODWORTH LOOP PALMER 99645',
'3260 HOSPITAL DR JUNEAU 99801',
'1650 COWLES STREET FAIRBANKS 99701',
'2801 DEBARR ROAD ANCHORAGE 99508']

['"'+str(x)+'"' for x in words]
```

**Output:**

```
['"3200 PROVIDENCE DRIVE ANCHORAGE 99508"',
 '"2500 SOUTH WOODWORTH LOOP PALMER 99645"',
 '"3260 HOSPITAL DR JUNEAU 99801"',
 '"1650 COWLES STREET FAIRBANKS 99701"',
 '"2801 DEBARR ROAD ANCHORAGE 99508"']
```

Comment: Add a note on why this should work.